# jQuery - POSTing with JSON and receiving both JSON and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML page, that posts JSON information to the server.

If the server thinks there is an error with the information posted, it returns a JSON string so that the client can modify the current HTML page with an error message.

Otherwise, the server returns a new HTML page.

How can I handle this in jQuery?

Comment: You should not used mixed return formats – thereby you’re leaving it to the client to figure out which is which, and that’s just bad design. Return your HTML code (or whatever it is you are returning) as JSON as well – f.e. by returning an `error` and a `data` property in your JSON response. If `error` is false/empty/not set, then the client can take that to mean “no error occurred”, and proceed with processing what you send him in `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, then you can put the html page content into a json variable and still return it as a json. In that way you would be still following practice.

Example:

PHP pseudo code:

```
if($ok) //you condition here
    {
    $html = file_get_contents("newPage.php");
    $toEcho = array("status"=>"true" , "message"=>"successful", "html"=>html);
    $json_parsed = JOSN_encode($toEcho);
    echo $json_parsed;
     }
else
{
    $toEcho = array("status"=>"false" , "message"=>"Wrong information", "html"=>false);
    $json_parsed = JOSN_encode($toEcho);
    echo $json_parsed;
}
```

JS pseudo code:

```
$.ajax({
url: "yourUrl.php",
type: "post",
data:"json"    
}).done(function (result){
       if(result.status==="true")
        {
          if(result.html)
           {
             $("#oldDiv").html(result.html);
           }
        }
        else if(result.message)
               {
                 $("#errorMsg").html(result.message);
               }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. But if HTML is returned, I want it to be on a separated URL, not the existing page. Do you think I should just return the URL, and then use `window.location` in JavaScript to redirect the user.

Comment: If your site is ajax oriented designed. Then you can return the whole html and replace it with current html and then, change the url using jquery without redirecting the user. But if your site is reguler hyper text oriented with normal <a href> stuff. Just yeah just return the url and have the url and redirect with window.location. It will be simpler and more structured that way.

Comment: The third option is to have the user submit the data as a normal form, not using ajax and then do all the validation and stuff on the server. If there was an error, show the message, otherwise take the user to the correct page. But that is not what is ajax for right.

Answer (score 1):

It's bad practice but you can try parse the response:

```
$.ajax({ url: " ....URL...." , type:"POST" , data:{.. your variables ..} })
 .done(function(response) {

      var tryRes = false;
      try { response = $.parseJSON(response); tryRes = true; } 
      catch (e) { }

      if (tryRes) {  

           //JSON ~ resonse is allready an object

      } else {

           //OTHER ~ HTML
      }


  }).fail(function(response) {  

      //Bad request

  });
```